# SELECT only on row from a couple unordered identical rows SQL/PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by, distinct

I am trying to get only one of the two rows given the next table:

```
| fn1 |  o1  |  d1  |    date    | fn2 |  o2  |  d2  |
------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | ATL  | PEK  | 2018-09-29 |  7  | PEK  | ATL  |
|  7  | PEK  | ATL  | 2018-09-29 |  1  | ATL  | PEK  |
```

I will refer to the first row as R1 and to the second as R2.

In general cases I need to check that:

> R1.fn1 = R2.dn2 AND R1.fn2 = R2.fn1 AND R1.o1 = R1.d2 = R2.d1 = R2.o1 AND R1.d1 = R1.o2 = R2.o1 = R2.d2
>   AND  R1.date = R2.date

If that is true for any 2 given rows in my table I need to group them to only one.
I do not know if there is a way to solve it using Group By or Distinct.
I have tried several queries but I am never able to delete the redundancy in the end.

To give more info I  will explain where the table provided comes from. I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE flights (
flightNumber SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
origin CHAR(3) REFERENCES airports(code),
destination CHAR(3) REFERENCES airports(code),
departureTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
seatsNumber INT NOT NULL,
airlineAbv VARCHAR(10) REFERENCES airlines(abv));
```

I need a query to check possible round trips on the same day.
For that I used:

```
CREATE VIEW AtoB AS
SELECT flightNumber fN1, origin o1, destination d1, departureTime::DATE dT1
FROM flights;

CREATE VIEW BtoA AS
    SELECT flightNumber fN2, origin o2, destination d2, departureTime::DATE dT2
    FROM flights;

CREATE VIEW AtoBtoA AS
    SELECT * FROM AtoB, BtoA WHERE o1 = d2 AND o2 = d1 AND dT1 = dT2;
```

And from the last query I get a very similar table to the one in the example. The one in the example is a bit simpler just so that is easier to explain the concept of what I want to achieve.

I hope I made clear my problem.

Ps: Here you have my whole database to see the design. I guess it could be useful.

```
CREATE TABLE airports (
    code CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE airlines (
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    abv VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE passengers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE flights (
    flightNumber SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    origin CHAR(3) REFERENCES airports(code),
    destination CHAR(3) REFERENCES airports(code),
    departureTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    seatsNumber INT NOT NULL,
    airlineAbv VARCHAR(10) REFERENCES airlines(abv)
);

CREATE TABLE bookings (
    passengerId INT REFERENCES passengers(id),
    bookDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    price REAL NOT NULL,
    flightId INT REFERENCES flights(flightNumber)
);
```

Comment: Are you looking to delete the rows or just show the unique set?

Comment: just show the unique set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your list of tables is.  However for your original question, you can use `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where fn1 < fn2 and o1 = d2 and d1 = o2 or
      (o1 <> d2 or d1 <> o2)
union all
select t.*
from t t2
where fn1 > fn2 and o1 = d2 and d1 = o2 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.fn1 = t.fn2 and t2.fn2 = t2.fn1 and
                        t2.o1 = t.d1 and t2.d1 = t.o1 and
                        t2.date = t.date
                 );
```